# Changing label color when a textfield is selected

Tags: html, css

I've a contact form and I want to change the label color when the user selects the textfield. The issue is that the change happens to the next label. For example: if I select textbox1, it should change label1 color. But in my case it change label2 color.

[image: img]

Please check the live site:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35853519/Contact/contact.html

```
form input[type="text"]:focus
{
    border: 2px solid #5187c4;
}

input:focus + label
{
    color: red;
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Could you post a bit of your code here so that we can see what you're doing without having to look through the entire live site?

Comment: [**How to ask a good question**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - [**Making an Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You are using the adjacent sibling combinator incorrectly.  It selects the next adjacent child, not the previous adjacent child.  That is why your current code is not working.

Comment: @Michael Yes that's the problem. Didn't know how to solve.

Comment: You could make the CSS code work by reorganizing your HTML so that the label comes "after" the input in the HTML structure.  That kills your formatting though, which means you'll have to do some nasty absolute positioning to get the text to appear where you want it again.

The other solution would be to use jquery/javascript...

Comment: This is beyond hackish - but it works. http://jsfiddle.net/83w8Y/ Until they add a "-" selector :O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved with javascipt as there is no "previous sibling" selector in css.

You can use the below jquery code

JS:

```
    $('form input[type="text"], form textarea').focus(function() {
      $("label[for='" + this.id + "']").addClass("labelfocus");
    }).blur(function() {
      $("label.labelfocus").removeClass("labelfocus");
    });
```

CSS:

```
.labelfocus{ color:red; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're doing now to get this to work as you have not posted any code, but perhaps try giving your labels an id and then changing their style using JavaScript?

For example:

```
<form>
   <label for="name" id="name-label">Your name</label>
   <input type="text" id="name" onclick="changeColor();">
</form>

<script>
    function changeColor() {
        var myLabel = document.getElementById("name-label");
        myLabel.style.color = "red";
    }
</script>
```

This is just a very quick mock-up, the real code would be more complex. For example you would have to support more than one entry/label pair, and you would have to  make the previous label that turned red to turn black again when you click on a different input form; but that shouldn't be too bad.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "previous sibling" selector. You might have to use JQuery or Javascript for this...

[Selectors level 4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject) will allow you to select the pervious sibling of the selector.

If you would like to use JQuery for this...

Try this:

```
$('form input').focus(function () {
    $(this).parent().addClass('red');
}).blur(function () {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('red');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the adjacent sibling selector (`+`), which only selects the immediately following child. This is contrary to your desired behaviour, which is selecting the preceding element.

Unfortunately there is [no such selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/css-previous-sibling-selector) in CSS, and I couldn't think of a good and easy solution. Unless you're okay with using *JavaScript* of course.

Another way might be to swap the places of your input boxes and labels, so that each input box is being followed by the label. This would of course mess up your formatting, so you need to re-position the labels to get them on top of the input fields again.